# Как передать переменную во вложенный запрос Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Есть запрос составленный через конструктор запросов Laravel

```
$y = substr($req->date_begin,0,4);    
$m = substr($req->date_begin,5,2);
$consumption =  $consumption->where("date_part('year',charge.date_begin)", '>', $y)
->orWhere(function ($query){
   $query->where("date_part('year',charge.date_begin)", '=', $y) // ОШИБКА
   ->where("date_part('month',charge.date_begin)", '>=',$m); // ОШИБКА
});
```

в подзапросе не видит переменные `$y` и `$m`. Как их туда передать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать `use`

```
$y = substr($req->date_begin,0,4);
$m = substr($req->date_begin,5,2);
$consumption =  $consumption->where("date_part('year',charge.date_begin)", '>', $y)
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($y, $m){
        $query->where("date_part('year',charge.date_begin)", '=', $y) 
        ->where("date_part('month',charge.date_begin)", '>=',$m); 
    });
```

Comment: благодарю, а то в документации такого не видал.